# How to open a file with emacsclient from Thunar?

Tags: emacsclient

I want to use emacsclient to open files from Thunar in Linux Mint 17 xfce.
I have tried right-click+"open with other application"+"emacsclient -c", but this does nothing.

I have also tried writing a custom emacsclient.desktop launcher.
Emacs daemon is running and works when emacsclient is invoked from the terminal. Also, using just "emacs" as the preferred program works.
Can this be done in Thunar?

Answer (score 10):

Thunar implements Freedesktop's [desktop entry specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html), so a `.desktop` entry is the answer you are looking for.  Try saving this to `$XDG_DATA_HOME/applications/emacs.desktop` or `$HOME/.local/share/applications/emacs.desktop` [if you don't have that set](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html#variables).

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Emacs
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Edit text
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascal;text/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
Exec=emacsclient -c -a "" %F
Icon=emacs
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;TextEditor;
StartupWMClass=Emacs
```

This will take precedence over any `emacs.desktop` in `/usr/share/applications`.  You may need to logout and and login again before it works, but now when you select Emacs from "open with" it will either attach to the running daemon, or start one and attach if it was not already running.

Comment: If this works, fine, but I don't see why this would work and not what the OP tried first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I use it like `Exec=emacsclient -c -a 'emacs -Q' %F`. It launches Emacs, not as a server, in case it's not already running. It's very fast due to `-Q`.  I don't prefer the silent server start (`-a ""`), since I have `(unless (server-running-p) (server-start))` in my `.emacs`.